# GAE: JAVA- update only one field in a particular row of an entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The requirement is to update the field of one of the rows in the entity. But the below code is updating entity row. Where am I making a mistake?

```
//Inserting
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

//Util.getKey() always returns current Date    
Key ky=KeyFactory.createKey("Routine", Util.getKey());

Entity e = new Entity("Routine",ky);
e.setProperty("running", Constants.RUNNING_INCREDIBLE);
datastore.put(e);

//Updating 
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Key ky=KeyFactory.createKey("Routine", Util.getKey());

Entity e2=datastore.get(ky);    

e2.setProperty("bAS", Constants.BAS_INCREDIBLE);
datastore.put(e);
```

Comment: Should the last line be `datastore.put(e2)`?

Comment: sorry..thats typo it is e2 only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. There is no difference between insert and update in Datastore.

From the documentation:

> The Cloud Datastore API **does not distinguish between creating a new**
>   **entity and updating an existing one**. If the object's key represents an
>   entity that already exists, the put() method overwrites the existing
>   entity. You can use a transaction to test whether an entity with a
>   given key exists before creating one.

You can refer to the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creating-entities#Java_Updating_entities)

Additionally, if you are updating a field too quickly consider using MemCache.

If you want to take care of transactions, look at:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
try {
  Key employeeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", "Joe");
  Entity employee = datastore.get(employeeKey);
  employee.setProperty("vacationDays", 10);

  datastore.put(txn, employee);

  txn.commit();
} finally {
  if (txn.isActive()) {
    txn.rollback();
  }
}
```

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions)

Comment: Then how can i update only particular filed of existing row of entity..You mean to say its Impossible

Comment: @user1742919 you are updating a particular field. if mean to say how will you take care of concurrent writes to the same entity row, then have a look at transactions. I have updated the answer

Comment: @user1742919 consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you